# Cannot find 'tools.jar' on ubuntu 18.04 when using maven

Tags: java, maven

I tried building a custom Jenkins-Plugin using Maven. Here is the issue:

My project depends on `org.kohsuke.args4j` (https://github.com/kohsuke/args4j). I've added the dependency in my pom.xml-file.

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kohsuke.metainf-services</groupId>
      <artifactId>metainf-services</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kohsuke.args4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>args4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.33</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

---

## The Problem

Apparently, this project requires somehow the *tools.jar* executable - which cannot be found.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project commit-pipeline-xml: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.siemens.plugins:commit-pipeline-xml:hpi:0.1: Could not find artifact jdk:tools:jar:5.0 at specified path /usr/local/java/jdk-14.0.2/../lib/tools.jar`

For my installation (see next paragraph) the path is wrong anyways, but I cannot even find *tools.jar* in */usr/local/java/jdk-14.0.2/lib/tools.jar* where I would expect this file. A `ls -l on $JAVA_HOME/lib` outputs some files (mostly *.so) but no *tools.jar*. Also `find $JAVA_HOME -name "tools"` exposes nothing.

---

### Installation of the jdk

For building my project the I'm using docker with ubuntu 18.04 as base. The jdk gets installed by downloading the tar.gz from [oracle.com](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html) and installing it using the commands:

```sh
mkdir -p /usr/local/java
cd /usr/local/java
tar xzvf "$JAVA_JDK_PATH"
ls -l ./jdk-$JAVA_JDK_VERSION/bin
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk-$JAVA_JDK_VERSION/bin/java" 1 
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk-$JAVA_JDK_VERSION/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set javac "/usr/local/java/jdk-$JAVA_JDK_VERSION/bin/javac"
ls -ld /usr/bin/java*
ls -ld /etc/alternatives/java*
```

`$JAVA_JDK_PATH` denotes the path of the downloaded zip-file and `$JAVA_JDK_VERSION` the jdk-version to download.

Note: **I assume the installation works, since I can typically build other maven projects.**

How to I install the jdk in order to get the *tools.jar* file?

Comment: Not that this is much of a solution, but the `tools.jar` has been removed from the JDK with Java9: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-D867DCCC-CEB5-4AFA-9D11-9C62B7A3FAB1

Comment: @Hans: I just read throgh this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707666/how-to-get-tools-jar-for-openjdk-11-on-windows) and it says the same. I was hoping for better news that this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible any more since JDK9, according to @Hans and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707666/how-to-get-tools-jar-for-openjdk-11-on-windows).

Closed.