# How to reference tools.jar from Eclipse, regardless of path

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

In my company, we check our Eclipse `*.launch` files into source control. How can we reference `tools.jar` (which is part of the JDK installation) from a launch file regardless of where the user installed his JDK? For example, if one user installed his JDK in `/opt/java` and another in `c:\Program Files\Java`, how can we write a launch file that works for both?

Note: I am happy to use a system variable such as `$JAVA_HOME`, but requiring the user to define a variable in Eclipse kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Note: tools.jar doesn't existing at all from Java 9 onwards [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53707739/2670892)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "Classpath Variable" to contain the path.

These are created in the Eclipse Preferences in 'Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables' and will be specific to that workspace.

You can use these in the launch "Dependencies" tab. Click the "Advanced..." button and choose "Add Classpath Variable".